# Vulnerabilities found in PyJWT back in 2015

Tags: python, jwt, flask-jwt, pyjwt

Just wanted to confirm something related to Flask-JWT using PyJWT library. Back in 2015 (https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/) vulnerability issue was found with PyJWT.

I'm not sure if that has been fixed now for Flask-JWT or still have to do a work around? Can't find much information out there.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: A maintained library won't have vulnerability left for 2 years.

Comment: That's the thing! last commit for flask-jwt on github was two years ago! so not sure

Comment: It is maintained. Is your Google broken? https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt

Comment: my bad, question was missing information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original Flask-JWT library is no longer maintained, and for any reason you shouldn't use such libraries unless there's no alternative.

It seems the PyJWT library that it depends already has the [fix](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v100), and Flask-JWT specifies a sufficient version in the dependency.

Anyway, here's an up-to-date alternative that I found: https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets I would appreciate you accepting the answer if this helps.